# Can someone explain the difference between the code snippets I've mentioned below?

Tags: r

I've borrowed this code snippet from a website.

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)

testing <- scale(BostonHousing[, c("age", "nox")])
set.seed(5)
## A random sample of 5 data points
startSet <- sample(1:dim(testing)[1], 5)
```

I later modified the startset object with my own piece of code which is something like this:

```
set.seed(5)
startSet<- sample(1:nrow(testing)[1], 5)
```

When I ran both codes simultaneously, I got the same results.

Can someone explain the difference between using dim and nrow. Even though both are different functions, why did they return the same value.

Please help me as I am new to R and trying to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not much to explain here:

```
> nrow
function (x) 
dim(x)[1L]
<bytecode: 0x103ccf5f0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

As you can see `nrow` is just a function of `dim`. So `nrow(x)` is like calling `dim(x)[1L]`